# Joomla 3.4 Category Blog displaying articles in a table instead of blog format

Tags: joomla-3.x

I recently updated to Joomla 3.4, seemingly without issue. However today I'm trying to create a new Category Blog section on our site and it isn't displaying as expected. Instead of showing the articles in the typical blog format, it is displaying a table with a list of the articles.

From what I can tell, the page https://jadencabinets.com/getting-started/idea-gallery is pulling components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/default.php to render `<div class="category-list">` instead of `<div class="blog">` and I can't for the life of me figure out why. The menu item is a Category Blog. The layout in global configuration for category is set to Blog.

What's even stranger is that if you click on a link to one of the subcategories https://jadencabinets.com/getting-started/idea-gallery/508-shaker-white or https://jadencabinets.com/getting-started/idea-gallery/509-leo-saddle, they both display just fine.

Any ideas/suggestions here? I'd greatly appreciate it.

UPDATE: I had created a category blog override a while back to test something and never renamed the option in its .xml file, so it was showing up as the Category Blog option when creating a menu item. DOH!

Comment: Did you set the menu item to Category List and then change it? Maybe things are cached. I have a number of sites running 3.4 and haven't seen this problem.

Comment: Nope, @isherwood, it's a brand new Menu Item that has never been a Category List. So stumped here...

Comment: Try changing the type, saving, then changing back. Clear site cache after.

Comment: Still no luck. I've tried changing it and changing it back, clearing the cache, moving the articles directly into the main category instead of subcategories, all to no avail. Any other ideas out there?

Comment: Make a new menu item. See if it happens again.